# How to pick a file (OpenDialog) in a .NET console app for Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, openfiledialog

Is it possible to use the native file picker to select a file from a .NET console app on MacOS? Is there a different way to pick files, or am I likely missing some references?

I've been trying to use the standard System.Windows.Forms OpenFileDialog, which I thought would work through Mono, but to no avail. I'm using VS2017 for Mac and I have the standard .NET packages installed.

Doesn't sound like it should be a complex task but I can't seem to find any concrete guidance online. Thanks!

Comment: A console app shouldn't show a GUI file picker at all....why do you think you need one?

Comment: depends on your framework....

Answer (score 1):

No, Mono implements [its own FileDialog](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Windows.Forms/System.Windows.Forms/FileDialog.cs), otherwise the burden of providing an implementation would be forwarded to the Mono runtime, where each OS-specific runtime would show a native UI. The Mono team chose not to do that.

Comment: Do you know how to set the `InitialDirectory` for an `OpenFileDialog` in a Windows Form Application that is running on Linux (through Mono)? The file browser works but it doesn't seem to accept any initial directory using either `\` or `/`.

Answer (score 0):

As its name implies, `System.Windows.Forms` is not part of the standard .Net and as such it is expected to work only on the Windows application development using Windows.Forms UI (it wouldn't work even on Windows on Universal Windows Platform).

Considering Mono, it maps macOS Cocoa controls, so there is `NSOpenPanel` class for that: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoMac.AppKit.NSOpenPanel/

Not sure how it works from the Console, but `System.Windows.Forms` surely can't because it is not implemneted in Mono in any way.